# SharePoint Date Formula

Tags: excel, calculated-column-formula

Let's say you have a date formatted as 31/Dec/16 but wanted to calculate two cells over to show 201612. How would I put in this formula because excel and sharepoint do not have it already formatted in the system?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below formula

```
=YEAR([DateField]) + MONTH([DateField])
```

OR

```
=TEXT([DateField], "YYYYMM")
```

Comment: I'll see what it comes up with.

Comment: Used the formula above for the date 29-Jul-16 and it comes out to be 2023?

Comment: Check my updated answer

Comment: Amal Hashim - WORKED

Comment: Now the formula won't stay when I hit refresh from an external data connection?